# Scrolling one element & e.preventDefault()

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, mobile-safari

I am making a mobile web app. I am using preventDefault() to prevent accidental scrolling of the window...

```
document.ontouchmove = function(e){ 
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

This works great, however, I need to scroll the content of one div. I have a seen a couple methods that don't seem to work , including the one below... has anyone figured out a good solve for this?

Thanks.

```
document.ontouchmove = function(e){ 
   var $target = $(e.target);
   if($target.is('list-container')){
     //do nothing
   }else{
     e.preventDefault(); 
   }
}
```

Comment: if `list-container` is a class add `.` in front of it. Hopefully that should do it.

Comment: or if it is the id the # in front, $target.is('#list-container')